# DidSelectRow method not called

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbardelegate

Hi guys I have been trying for few days no answer found . I have already implemented `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` before raising this question my `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt`, both the methods are not working. [image]

```
class SearchClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!

var objects:PFObject!

var searchResults = [String]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Search"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.searchResults.removeAll()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.mySearchBar.delegate = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self


    self.navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    //self.myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
   // self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.mySearchBar.endEditing(true)
    print("Search word = \(searchBar.text)")

    let query = PFQuery(className:"myClass")
    //let newText = searchBar.autocapitalization
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    searchBar.text = searchBar.text?.localizedLowercase
    query.whereKey("collegeNickName", contains: searchBar.text)

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (results, error) in
        if error == nil {

            if let objects = results {

                self.searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

                for object in objects {
                    let firstName = object.object(forKey: "myName") as! String
                    let image = object.object(forKey: "myImage") as! PFFile
                    //   let lastName = object.object(forKey: "myPlace") as! String
                    //   let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
                    self.searchResults.append(firstName)

                    print(self.searchResults[0])
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                        self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return


                }
            }
        }

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")

    let myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")

    myCell?.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    print(searchResults[indexPath.row])
    return myCell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Hi")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mySearchBar.text = ""
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    //self.mySearchBar.endEditing(true)
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

@IBAction func refreshButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mySearchBar.text = ""
    self.searchResults.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Also it implements a searchView I'm getting what I want to search but unable use select and deselect methods in my class.

Comment: Bind your `datasource` too as you done with `delegate.`

Comment: I did that earlier but the app crashes when I open the SearchTab

Comment: Wait for 5 mint I am checking.

Comment: Delete your `delegate` from the `storyboard` because you have done from the code, so you do need to repeat the delegates otherwise conflicts are create in xcode and may be  thats why your app is crashed. And pls ensure your  `delegate` & `datasource` are connected properly to its UIViewController is you'r binding delegate from storyboard.

Comment: add this line `self.myTableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: thanks buddy I got my mistake

Comment: Follow the right format for tableview, I have maintained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.myTableView.dataSource = self
self.myTableView.delegate = self
```

<--- add this.

Comment: add it to your code. you have only .datasource = self there as far as I can see

Comment: I was seeing `mySearchView.delegate` as `myTableView.delegate` working like a charm. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you've set delegate in the storyboard as `view` instead of your `UIViewController`
[see Discover - that's mine UViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McanV.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder

- Connect `dataSource` **and** `delegate` of `My Table View` to `SearchClass`

Then you can delete redundant `self.myTableView.dataSource = self` in `SearchClass`

Consider that connections in Interface Builder are more efficient than in code.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of cell is wrong. you have done this below code

```
 let myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Right format

```
 let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")
```

**Reason:** When you use dequeue property, then `UITableView` dequeue its cell by the param it got from the method

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

see there is a param `tableView` but you are dequeing by the outllet of `UITableView`.